# Buscando o próximo registro e o registro anterior usando duas colunas para ordenação de tabelas diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de banco de dados:

```
___ Table: modules___
id int(10)
name varchar(50)
position int(10)

___ Table: lessons ___
id int(10)
module_id int(10) FK
position int(10)
name varchar(50)
```

Considerando que tenhos os seguintes dados para a tabela modules:

```
1 - 1 - Módulo 1
2 - 2 - Módulo 2
3 - 3 - Módulo 3
```

E para a tabela lessons tenho os seguintes dados:

```
1 - 1 - 1 - Aula 1
2 - 1 - 2 - Aula 2
3 - 1 - 3 - Aula 3
4 - 1 - 4 - Aula 4

5 - 2 - 1 - Aula 1
6 - 2 - 2 - Aula 2
7 - 2 - 3 - Aula 3
8 - 2 - 4 - Aula 4

9  - 3 - 1 - Aula 1
10 - 3 - 2 - Aula 2
11 - 3 - 3 - Aula 3
12 - 3 - 4 - Aula 4
```

Então, eu tenho a seguinte query buscando uma aula:

```
SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE id = 8
```

Na query acima a próxima aula seria a lesson com id 9 e a aula anterior seria a lesson com id 7.

Como fazer as querys acima, sendo que a paginação dependerá da position tanto da tabela modules como da tabela lessons?

Eu já tentei baseado na position da tabela lessons pegar a próxima aula assim:

```
SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE position > 4 ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1;
```

No caso o número 4 é a position da da lesson com id 8. Só que claro que não pegou já que não tem nenhuma position maior que 4.

Tentei também na coluna position da tabela lessons guardar os valores assim:

```
0000000001.0000000001
0000000001.0000000002
0000000001.0000000003
0000000001.0000000004

0000000002.0000000001
0000000002.0000000002
0000000002.0000000003
0000000002.0000000004

0000000003.0000000001
0000000003.0000000002
0000000003.0000000003
0000000003.0000000004
```

Seguindo o padrão MODULE_ID.LESSON_ID mas acredito que não seria uma boa opção já que a ordenação de modules e lessons podem ser mudadas.

Gostaria de saber como fazer da melhor forma. Se tenho que pensar em outra estrutura de banco de dados ou como fazer as querys para pegar a lesson anterior e a próxima lesson.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa primeiro fazer a junção das duas tabelas, e então estabelecer a condição desejada (mesmo módulo e posição superior/inferior, ou módulo superior/inferior):

```
SELECT *
FROM lessons l
  JOIN modules m on l.module_id = m.id
WHERE (m.position = 2 AND l.position > 4) OR m.position > 2
ORDER BY m.position ASC, l.position ASC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT *
FROM lessons l
  JOIN modules m on l.module_id = m.id
WHERE (m.position = 2 AND l.position < 4) OR m.position < 2
ORDER BY m.position DESC, l.position DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/120d30/7/1). Na hora de ordenar, ele considera primeiro o módulo depois a posição dentro do módulo.

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou como eu precisava. Valeu :)